# PHP Session Variable will not change

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I have a form that consists of 4 radio buttons, each radio button represents a different shape either cuboid, cone, cylinder or sphere, I also have a session variable for each of those shapes ( each one is set to 0), when a user selects a radio button and submits the form I want it to add 1 to whatever shape was selected here is my code

HTML

```
<form action="question2.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="cuboid">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="cone">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="cylinder">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="sphere">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset( $_POST['ans'])) {
             $selected_answer = $_POST['ans'];
             if($selected_answer == "cuboid") {
                 $_SESSION["cuboid"] = ((int)Session["cuboid"]) + 1;
             }
        }
    }
?>
```

However this is not working. $_SESSION["cuboid"] just stays 0. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

EDIT - I am defining the Session variable in a previous page like this

```
$_SESSION["cuboid"] = 0;
```

And also I have the following at the top of all my pages

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Comment: did you check if all conditions where met? FYI `isset()` can take more than one parameter.

Comment: Do you mean have an if statement for each radio button? Im not sure what you mean by it being able to take more than one parameter?

Comment: `((int)Session["cuboid"])` wrong syntax. Should be `(int)$_SESSION["cuboid"]` - you also need `session_start();` and to define the variable it when it's never set.

Comment: The `$_SESSION` array is called `$_SESSION` and not `Session` which MUST be generating an error of some sort somewhere. Find your PHP ERROR LOG and review it often, or while testing add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of all your scripts.

Comment: Don't expect this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` to ever fire.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Excellent catch!

Comment: @Script47 It's always the first thing I check, conditionals.

Comment: actually your if is not being called if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
as submit input dont have name="submit" and it is Submit it should be submit

Answer (score 4):

You need to use use [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), if you haven't done so already.

You also have a syntax error which should be showing if you have a error reporting enabled.

Change,

```
$_SESSION["cuboid"] = ((int)Session["cuboid"]) + 1;
```

To,

```
$_SESSION["cuboid"] = ((int)$_SESSION["cuboid"]) + 1;
```

### Another thing...

Your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional check will never run, as you have not actually set the `name` property for it.

**Error Reporting**

To enable error reporting to see any errors that you make,

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: I am using session_start I just didn't include that in my code above

Comment: ^ isn't that always the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sadly, yes.

Comment: Note to @Dfarrelly If you ask a question that contains a reference to `$_SESSION` always add the `session_start()` in your example code or thats the first thing you will get comments about as it is very often forgotten by beginners

Comment: @Script47 You might want to add the bit about input tags without `name=""` attributes dont get sent to the script

Comment: I see the guy never even tested your answer; given the added "tool". *sigh*

Comment: @RiggsFolly Added the catch.

Comment: Your answer is right however when the form is submitted I am loading a new page with another set of questions but the updated session variable isn't moving across to the second page it just stays at 0